# Pandas: select by bigger than a value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has a column called `dir`, it has several values, I want to know how many the values passes a certain point. For example:

```
df['dir'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

It returns a `Series`

```
0       855
20      881
40     2786
70     3777
90     3964
100       4
110    2115
130    3040
140       1
160    1697
180    1734
190       3
200     618
210       3
220    1451
250     895
270    2167
280       1
290    1643
300       1
310    1894
330       1
340     965
350       1
Name: dir, dtype: int64
```

Here, I want to know the number of the value passed 500. In this case, it's all except 100, 140, 190,210, 280,300,330,350.

How can I do that?

I can get away with `df['dir'].value_counts()[df['dir'].value_counts() > 500]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df['dir'].value_counts() > 500).sum()
```

This gets the value counts and returns them as a series of Truth Values.  The parens treats this whole thing like a series.  `.sum()` counts the True values as 1 and the False values as 0.